# CSS : before triangle has strange transparent border in FF but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've made a classic CSS: before triangle and in chrome, it looks nice but in Firefox, I've got a strange issue where the triangle has a transparent border in the middle. Is that a browser rendering error or just the wrong code?

[image]

```
content: " ";
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 15px 35px 15px 0;
display: block;
vertical-align: middle;
border-color: transparent #093 transparent transparent;
position: absolute;
transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg);
left: 50%;
top: -18px;
```

Comment: Its working fine on my version of `Firefox 72.0.2`

Comment: Try inspecting what is causing the border. Most likely it looks a margin issue to me.